# Preservation of inequality with difference of concave functions

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Suppose for some value of $z$ I have an inequality

$$f \left( \phi(z) + \gamma_1(z)\right) - f\left(\phi(z) + \gamma_2(z)\right) < c,$$

where $\phi$ is decreasing in $z$ and $\gamma_i$ is increasing in $z$ for $i=1,2$. All values are positive.

I am interested in how this inequality is preserved as we vary $z$. Specifically, suppose this inequality holds for some $z_0$. When will it also hold for any $z<z_0$?

For instance, when $f$ and $\gamma_i$ are linear, decreasing $z$ should preserve the inequality. However, what if $f$ is concave? My conjecture is that the inequality is still preserved in such a case. What methods can I use to prove this and understand how the inequality is preserved for other assumptions on $f,\phi,\gamma_i$?

Comment: If all are continuous and \}\gamma_i\}_{i=1,2} is equicontinuous don't works?

Comment: @vvnitram Do you mean when $f$ is weakly concave? I don't think $f$ convex works. Example: if $f(x)=x^5$, $\phi(z)=3(1-z)$, $\gamma_1(z)=2z$, and $\gamma_2(z)=z$. Then, for $c=32$, the inequality holds for z=0, z=1, but not $z=.5$.

Comment: but $\epsilon=0.5$ is so much! Haha. In this case, define "vary" please

Comment: @vvnitram Ah yes, I see what you mean--I was unclear. Suppose this inequality holds for some $z_0$. When will it also hold for any $z<z_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Even if we assume that $f(x)=x$ for each $x$, the required inequality transforms to the inequality

$$\gamma_1(z) - \gamma_2(z) < c$$

for increasing functions $\gamma_i$. If it holds for $z=z_0$ then it may fails for some $z<0$. For instance, let $\gamma_1(z)=z$, $\gamma_2(z)=2z$, $z_0=0$, $z=-1$, and
$c=1$.